# Validate 'required' doesn't work for updating form in laravel6

Tags: laravel, requiredfieldvalidator

I made a form for editing and updating username.
The form is working correctly.

However, if make the username field empty and submit,
validate function "required" doesn't go off and get the error:

> "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name'
>   cannot be null"

I can't find why validation doesn't work.
Here is my code.

**UsernameController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use App\User;

class UsernameController extends Controller
{
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $data = User::findOrFail($id);
    return view('username.edit')->with('form',$data);
    }


    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $this->validate($request, ['name' => 'required']);
        $form = new User;
        $form = User::findOrFail($id);
        $form->name = $request->name;
        unset($form['_token']);
        $form->save();

        return redirect('/home/mypage')->with('status','Updated!');
    }
}
```

**edit.blade.php**

```
<form action="/username/{{$form->id}}" method="post">
@csrf
@method('PUT')
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$form->id}}">

<p>Username<br>
<input type="text" name="name" value="{{$form->name}}"></p>

@error('name')
<p><span style="color:red;">{{$message}}</span></p>
@enderror

<p><input type="submit" value="Update"></p>

</form>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::resource('username','UsernameController',['only' => ['edit', 'update']]);
```

Comment: try changing this `$this->validate($request, ['name' => 'required']);` to this `$this->validate($request->all(), ['name' => 'required']);`

Comment: ` $this->validate(request(), ['name' => 'required']);` Try and let us know

Comment: Unfortunately, both of codes didn't work and gave me the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following instead

```
use use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
//...
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
     'name' => 'required',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
     return redirect()->back()
         ->withErrors($validator)
         ->withInput();
}
```

**Edit**

You should, also, define which model attributes you want to make mass assignable. You may do this using the `$fillable` property on the model.

```
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = ['name'];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, it didn't work and gave me the same error.

Comment: I've been doing `protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];` , so if input field is filled with text, submit works with no problem. However, if input field is empty and submit, validation doesn't go off and get error.

Comment: hmm, did you tried the `Validator` facade instead ? Check the above code

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Now I found what was wrong. I had copied controller file for backup. this copied file was messing routing. Now working fine with your method.